# Multiple histograms on same graph with Seaborn `displot` (not `distplot`)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Seaborn `distplot` is deprecated.

With `distplot` I get the following graph

[image]

with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(random.normal(loc=177.8, scale=10.2, size=1000), kde=True)
sns.distplot(random.normal(loc=165.1, scale=8.9, size=1000), kde=True)

plt.show()
```

How do I achieve the same with `displot` please? If I just substitute `displot` for `distplot`, the histograms are displayed separately.

Comment: `distplot` has been replaced by `histplot` (histogram with options for kde-curves) and `kdeplot` (without histogram).  All three are "axes level functions", only acting on one subplot.   `displot` is s a similar function

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you want to use displot? Using `histplot` accomplishes your goal.